# Efficiency of query

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

How efficient is this query. It's selecting from the same table twice from within a sub-query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country, rowCount FROM 
(
    SELECT *, (
        SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl WHERE hide != 1 AND country = y.country
    ) AS rowCount FROM tbl y

) AS x
HAVING rowCount >= 1
ORDER BY x.country ASC
```

I have indexed the table where required and the query executes in "0.000 sec" (says HeidiSQL) so it must be good, however is there anything that would improve the structure of the query?

Comment: What does this query do?

Comment: It selects a list of distinct country names, where the amount of fields that have the same country code is more than or equal to 1.

Comment: It's unnecessarily complex (if I understand the problem correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it can be rewritten as a single query:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(id) rowCount
FROM tbl
WHERE hide <> 1
GROUP BY country
HAVING rowCount >= 1
```

Playground: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28978/1

Comment: That seems much better! Thanks!

Comment: @James: :) yeah, sqlfiddle is awesome. If only everyone used it in questions :)